# Problems writing a plugin to ida pro in c++ Because of different versions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, plugins, c++builder, ida

I'm trying to write a plugin for ida and I'm pretty stuck.
Im using the newest ida pro version (6.1).
It turns out that I used some things that not in use on this version.

How do I solve the problem in my code with the commands with HT_graph? 
To what this command changed in the new version?
And also if there is anyone with experience in writing plugins I'd love some tips.

Thank you :)

Comment: You haven't provided enough information.  What unsupported features are you using?  I don't know IDA, but the usual method when features become unsupported within a framework is to use the alternatives provided.

Comment: This is my Q..What is the alternatives provided and what is the diffrents between them.

Comment: And there is no documentation provided on the deprecated methods and their alternatives?

Comment: I haven't found anything yet that explains me how to make the changes in what I wrote.
Just found in the SDK that it is no longer in use.

Comment: So far, all I have found is [this changelog note](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/5.1/ida51news.pdf) in IDA 5.1: "SDK: **removed HT_GRAPH** and added 2 parameters to create_graph_viewer() This breaks the existing graph view plugins (sorry) but this part of IDA API has not been settled yet."

Comment: I know..this is why i dont know how to write my plugin..:/
Do you have any ideas on how you can i overcome this obstacle?

Comment: 6.1 is not "the newest". I guess you meant to say I'm using "the latest **pirated** version".

Comment: Does it help u to help me? so yes.. :)